# Adonis.js How do I set keys of object loaded by eager loading?

Tags: javascript, adonis.js

is there any way to set key of object loaded by eager loading? For example, I have two database tables:

1. pages
2. page_translations

In my Page model I have:

```
translations () {
    return this.hasMany('App/Models/PageTranslation'); 
}
```

When I do `await Page.query().with('translations').fetch();` My output is:

```
{
    id: 1,
    translations: [
        {
            language: 'cs'
            title: 'Moje první stránka',
            slug: 'moje-prvni-stranka'
        },
        {
            language: 'en',
            title: 'My first page',
            slug: 'my-first-page'
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to get output like this?

```
{
    id: 1,
    translations: {
        cs: {
            language: 'cs'
            title: 'Moje první stránka',
            slug: 'moje-prvni-stranka'
        },
        en: {
            language: 'en',
            title: 'My first page',
            slug: 'my-first-page'
        }
    }
}
```